# Is there an error in this textbook about Peano Arithmetic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I encountered this doubt in an online intro-logic open course offered by Stanford Uni.

Under the section 9.4 of this textbook here: http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/secondary/notes/chapter_09.html

It says:

> The axioms shown here define the same relation in terms of 0 and s.(where the functional constant letter s below represents the successor function, e.g. s(0)=1, s(1)=2, s(2)=3 )
>
> ∀x.same(x,x)
>
> ∀x.(¬same(0,s(x)) ∧ ¬same(s(x),0))
>
> ∀x.∀y.(¬same(x,y) ⇒ ¬same(s(x),s(y)))

As my understanding, :

The first sentence says two identical numbers are same. The second and third sentences are used to define what is not same.

The second says no successor of any number is same to 0.

The third says if two numbers are not the same, then their successors are not same. For example, if 1≠3, then 2≠4.

However, I think the third sentence **should be bi-conditional** because, if I'm not wrong, the definition didn't cover the instance where the number being testified are smaller than the given number,otherwise it is possible to say if 2≠4, then 1=3.

So I wondered is this an error in text book or there's something wrong of my reasoning.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax

Comment: Presumably the author assumes the "same" relation has a substitution property: if $\text{same}(t_1, t_2)$ then $\text{same}(s(t_1), s(t_2))$. That would handle the other direction of the implication. This substitution property is often included in the rules of deduction for logic with equality.

Comment: @CarlMummert I'd say it is included in 1st sentence : $\forall x, same(x,x) \rightarrow \forall x,same(s(x),s(x))$

Comment: You don't need to state the bi direction because the second sentence disallows 0=2 so 1 doesn't = 3.  Second line says if x ne 0 the x = s (y) for some y and 0 ne s (y).  Sentence the allows us to inductive do all cases.  So we don't need backwards direction.

Comment: You don't need to be able to go from $2 \ne 4$ to $1 ?? 3$.  By sentence 2 we know $0 \ne s(s (0))=2$ so $1 \ne 3$.  Indeed $1\ne 3$ is the only way we can get $2\ne4$ in the first place.  We're not ever going to be given any 2$\ne $4.  We will have to deduce *all* of them.

Comment: Carl mummert and user1952009.  The book makes no such claim and doesn't need to as  same(x,y) will never happen because same (0,x-y) is impossible.

Comment: Oh, I misread user1952009 s comment. If x != y then $\lnot same(x,y) $ via second 2 axioms. (Of course the entire point of "same" is to axiomatically define equals...but you know what I mean)

Comment: An unusual presentation. These days, the axioms of equality are not usually included in Peano's Axioms. The axioms of first order logic  and set theory take care of that. The successor relation $S$ on $N$ is usually given as a unary function such that $\forall x,y\in N:[S(x)=S(y)\implies x=y]$ (i.e. $S$ is injective) and  $\forall x\in N: S(x)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error here.  The book is asserting that these axioms are enough to determine whether any two particular natural numbers (of the form $s(s(\dots (s(0))\dots))$) are the same, as it explains after stating the definition.  It is not attempting to write down every single true statement about the "same" relation.  It is indeed true that the reverse implication of the third axiom holds for natural numbers, but it is not necessary to include this in the axiomatization in order to be able to determine whether any two particular natural numbers are the same.  Failing to include this reverse implication as an axiom doesn't mean they are claiming it isn't true; it just means that they don't need it as an assumption.

Comment: How do we prove within the theory presented there that the reverse implication holds? I can only see how it may hold when the numbers are given by closed terms. For concreteness, the thing that is under question is the implication $same(x,y) \to same(s(x),s(y))$.

Comment: Right, as I commented on fleablood's answer you can't actually prove that in this theory.  But this theory doesn't seem to be intended to be used as a first-order theory in the ordinary sense; it seems to only be intended to be able to prove things about closed terms.

Comment: Thanks; I was confused because the answer states that the reverse implication holds, but it doesn't (as far as I can tell from the somewhat vague original source)

Comment: Right, I was trying to avoid confusing OP with technicalities that seemed unrelated to the actual point they were asking about.

Comment: The reverse implication/bijection only holds by doing finite iterations for the specific n.  But that's okay.  One direction *is* sweeping.  The point is although there are infinite cases every case itself is finitely obtainable and we know that is so.

Comment: @fleablood: how to we know that  the system proves $same(x,y) \Rightarrow same(s(x),s(y))$?  The "case" there is just $x$ and $y$, which are not closed terms. That is the reverse imlication that the question is about.

Comment: x and y are closed items. Why do you say they are not?  We don't know their closed forms are but we chose them as two numbers with closed forms.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I actually read more of the source and see now that the author addressed this three paragraphs later

" Viewed the other way around, to see that two non-identical terms are not the same, we just strip away occurrences of s from each term till one of the two terms becomes 0 and the other one is not 0. By the second axiom, these are not the same, and so the original terms are not the same."

==== here's my much longer take===

The condition is *intentionaly* one directional for sufficiency.

You will *never* need to deduce $\lnot same (1,3) $ from $\lnot same (2,4) $ because the only way you will ever know that $\lnot same (2,4)$ in the first place is by deducing *it* from knowing $\lnot same (1,3) $ previously.

And the only way we'd know $\lnot same (1,3) $ previously is if we knew $\lnot same (0,2)$ even earlier.

Which we would have by Axiom 2:  $\lnot same (0,s (s (0))=2) $.

We will simply never need the other direction because we can deduce *everything* from one direction only.

====

Or put another way.  From these three axioms We can prove:

Theorem:  if $s (y') =y$ and $s (x')=x $ then $same(x,y) \iff same (x',y') $

Proof: if $\lnot same(x',y') $ then $\lnot same (x,y) $ by axiom 3.

If $same (x',y') $:

If $x'$ or $y'$ is 0 then both are 0 because otherwise $same (x',y') $ would violate axiom 2.  If both are 0 then x and y are both $s (0)$ are 1, and by axiom 1 $same (s (0),s (0)) $ and we'd be done.

If neither $x'$ or $y'$ are 0 there are $x''$ and $y''$ such that $s (x'') $ is $x'$ and $s (y'') $ is $y $. In which case we can repeat the argument until we determine that $x'$ and $y'$ are both $s (s(s (.....(0).....))) $ and so $x $ and $y $ are both the successor to that.

And so by axiom 1, $same (x,y) $ and we are done.

Moral: bidirectional should be a theorem.  Not an axiom.

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually not sure the proof in the second half works yet as we haven't determined predecessors are unique.  I.e. if s (x) is s (y) the x is y.  The is part of what the axioms are for.  Still I'm going to leave the proof up as it demonstrates... no I will redo it.... give me time....

Comment: The axioms given in the book are actually not enough to prove that $same(x,y)$ implies $same(s(x),s(y))$.  But it is clear that the axioms given are not meant to actually be an adequate foundation for first-order arithmetic (they include no induction schema, for instance).  It appears that they are intended only to be strong enough to evaluate all of the given predicates on any terms with no variables (i.e., any expressions of the form $s(s(\dots(s(0))\dots))$.)

Comment: I was assuming the induction schema were introduced elsewhere.  I think these are enough to prove same(x,y) implies same(s (x),s (y)) if you are given all numbers are either zero or a finite successor of 0.  But meh... you are right.  We need a lot more for a first order arithetic.  Including just vocabulary.

Comment: It seems as if you have only proved the final result for standard $n$, rather than proving it within the theory. The "we can repeat the argument..." part is a sign that the result only works when the numbers are given by closed terms.

Comment: I think this acceptable because we are operating that the only numbers available *were* given by a closed form.